# IE 11 Display Issue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11, recaptcha

Folks -

Longtime lurker, first time poster. I've found many answers here in the past, and have always appreciated the expertise. I'm a bit of a noob, so bear with me:

I have a landing page. It displays well in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and older versions of IE. All of the above include the the Google ReCaptcha - no issues, widgets work, etc.

IE 11 turns this to mush. My graphic fails to load, and it seems the recaptcha moves itself to the full width of the page instead of the small part I've intended.

Oddly enough, if I grab the sides of the browser window and adjust the width in any way (wider or narrower) the image snaps in where it should be, and the page looks perfect. Likewise, if I inspect the element, the page loads exactly as intended.

This seems like it should mean something to me, but my knowledge is too limited to get exactly what I'm being told. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

I can furnish source code and screenshots if that's required.

Regards, Cheers, and thanks for any thoughts -

*CDM*

Comment: You really need to post some code to get help. Read the following in order to get started: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Romulo - Could I email you at the address you have listed on your profile?

Comment: sure! but remember to edit the question and provide some code, so other people can help (and others with the same problem can benefit aswell)

Comment: @Romulo Done. Left you a note inside the message as well. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

@Romulo helped me tremendously with this issue. The entire page was being loaded by a script, and there were errors within the script itself that needed correcting. The solution required a style block to be moved, which solved the issue. This was probably a once-in-a-lifetime issue, but if you find this page and think this might be what you're dealing with, feel free to message me and I'll be happy to discuss further.